# Alinhar altura 3 divs em uma linha - bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, div

Tenho 3 divs em uma row, mas algumas ficam com alturas diferentes de acordo com o conteúdo da div.

Como padronizar a altura das div. (não quero fixar altura e sim que sejam da mesma altura.)

Meu html:

```
<div class="row-services-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-same-height">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="70" data-mobi="60" data-smobi="60" style="height:70px"></div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->                                        

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/5-1506976704.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="PINTURAS / TEXTURAS" title="PINTURAS / TEXTURAS">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="#">PINTURAS / TEXTURAS</a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Confira todos nossos serviços de Pinturas e Texturas
                                </div>
                                <div class="ib-btn">
                                    <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/6-1506976743.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="TELHADO" title="TELHADO">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="#">TELHADO</a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Confira todos nossos serviços de telhados
                                </div>
                                <div class="ib-btn">
                                    <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/4-1506976664.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="ASSENTAMENTO / REVESTIMENTOS" title="ASSENTAMENTO / REVESTIMENTOS">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="#">ASSENTAMENTO / REVESTIMENTOS</a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Confira todos nossos serviços de Assentamentos de revestimentos
                                </div>
                                <div class="ib-btn">
                                    <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        </div>

        <div class="row row-same-height">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="70" data-mobi="60" data-smobi="60" style="height:70px"></div>
            </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-12 -->                                        

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/2-1506976574.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="ADEQUAÇÃO HIDRÁULICA" title="ADEQUAÇÃO HIDRÁULICA">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="#">ADEQUAÇÃO HIDRÁULICA</a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Confira todos nossos serviços de adequação Hidráulica
                                </div>
                                <div class="ib-btn">
                                    <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/3-1506976625.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="ALVENARIAS / CONCRETAGEM" title="ALVENARIAS / CONCRETAGEM">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="#">ALVENARIAS / CONCRETAGEM</a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Confira todos nossos serviços de alvenarias e concretagem
                                </div>
                                <div class="ib-btn">
                                    <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/1-impermeabilizacao-1506976478.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="Impermeabilização" title="Impermeabilização">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrap">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="#">Impermeabilização</a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Confira todos nossos serviços de Impermeabilização
                                </div>
                                <div class="ib-btn">
                                    <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        </div>                                   
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca uma amostra do código dessas 3 divs.

Comment: adicionei o html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução (embora não esteja na lista de **tags** da pergunta) seria uma função jQuery:

```
<script>
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
    div_inner = $(".wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item .inner");
    if(div_inner.eq(0).width() >= window.innerWidth/2){
        div_inner.css("height","auto");
    }else{
        max_height = 0; div_col = 3; contador = 1; loop = 1;
        div_inner.css("height","").each(function(){
            if($(this).height() > max_height){
                max_height = $(this).height();
            }
            if(contador == div_col){
                for(x=(div_col*loop)-div_col;x<div_col*loop;x++){
                    div_inner.eq(x).css("height",max_height+"px");
                }
                max_height = 0; contador = 1; loop++;
            }else{
                contador++;
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

O script acima iguala o `height` de todas as `div .item` pela que tiver maior `height` em cada linha.

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
 div_inner = $(".wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item .inner");
 if(div_inner.eq(0).width() >= window.innerWidth/2){
  div_inner.css("height","auto");
 }else{
  max_height = 0; div_col = 3; contador = 1; loop = 1;
  div_inner.css("height","").each(function(){
   if($(this).height() > max_height){
    max_height = $(this).height();
   }
   if(contador == div_col){
    for(x=(div_col*loop)-div_col;x<div_col*loop;x++){
     div_inner.eq(x).css("height",max_height+"px");
    }
    max_height = 0; contador = 1; loop++;
   }else{
    contador++;
   }
  });
 }
});
```

```css
.wprt-image-box.has-shadow { margin: 0 -15px; }
.wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item { padding: 0px 15px 30px; }
.wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item .inner { background-color: #fff; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 300px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-services-1">
                    <div class="container">

                            <div class="row row-same-height">
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="70" data-mobi="60" data-smobi="60" style="height:70px">
                                    </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->                                        

                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                                                    <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                            <div class="inner">
                                                                <div class="thumb">
                                                                    <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/5-1506976704.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="PINTURAS / TEXTURAS" title="PINTURAS / TEXTURAS">                                                                    </div>
                                                                <div class="text-wrap">
                                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                                        <a href="#">PINTURAS / TEXTURAS</a>
                                                                    </h3>
                                                                    <div class="desc">
                                                                        Confira todos nossos serviços de Pinturas e Texturas                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="ib-btn">
                                                                        <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                                                    <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
                                                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                                                    <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                            <div class="inner">
                                                                <div class="thumb">
                                                                    <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/6-1506976743.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="TELHADO" title="TELHADO">                                                                    </div>
                                                                <div class="text-wrap">
                                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                                        <a href="#">TELHADO</a>
                                                                    </h3>
                                                                    <div class="desc">
                                                                        Confira todos nossos serviços de telhados                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="ib-btn">
                                                                        <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                                                    <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
                                                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                                                    <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                            <div class="inner">
                                                                <div class="thumb">
                                                                    <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/4-1506976664.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="ASSENTAMENTO / REVESTIMENTOS" title="ASSENTAMENTO / REVESTIMENTOS">                                                                    </div>
                                                                <div class="text-wrap">
                                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                                        <a href="#">ASSENTAMENTO / REVESTIMENTOS</a>
                                                                    </h3>
                                                                    <div class="desc">
                                                                        Confira todos nossos serviços de Assentamentos de revestimentos nossos serviços de Assentamentos de revestimentos                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="ib-btn">
                                                                        <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                                                    <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
                                                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                                                </div><div class="row row-same-height"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="70" data-mobi="60" data-smobi="60" style="height:70px"></div></div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->                                        

                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                                                    <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                            <div class="inner">
                                                                <div class="thumb">
                                                                    <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/2-1506976574.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="ADEQUAÇÃO HIDRÁULICA" title="ADEQUAÇÃO HIDRÁULICA">                                                                    </div>
                                                                <div class="text-wrap">
                                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                                        <a href="#">ADEQUAÇÃO HIDRÁULICA</a>
                                                                    </h3>
                                                                    <div class="desc">
                                                                        Confira todos nossos serviços de adequação Hidráulica                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="ib-btn">
                                                                        <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                                                    <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
                                                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                                                    <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                            <div class="inner">
                                                                <div class="thumb">
                                                                    <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/3-1506976625.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="ALVENARIAS / CONCRETAGEM" title="ALVENARIAS / CONCRETAGEM">                                                                    </div>
                                                                <div class="text-wrap">
                                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                                        <a href="#">ALVENARIAS / CONCRETAGEM</a>
                                                                    </h3>
                                                                    <div class="desc">
                                                                         Confira todos nossos serviços de alvenarias e concretagem                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="ib-btn">
                                                                        <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                                                    <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
                                                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->


                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-height">
                                                    <div class="wprt-image-box has-shadow clearfix">
                                                        <div class="item">
                                                            <div class="inner">
                                                                <div class="thumb">
                                                                    <img src="https://localhost/wc_marca/tim.php?src=uploads/images/2017/10/1-impermeabilizacao-1506976478.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;h=600" alt="Impermeabilização" title="Impermeabilização">                                                                    </div>
                                                                <div class="text-wrap">
                                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                                        <a href="#">Impermeabilização</a>
                                                                    </h3>
                                                                    <div class="desc">
                                                                        Confira todos nossos serviços de Impermeabilização                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <div class="ib-btn">
                                                                        <a class="small wprt-button outline" href="#">Conheça Mais...</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div><!-- /.wprt-image-box -->

                                                    <div class="wprt-spacer clearfix" data-desktop="0" data-mobi="35" data-smobi="35" style="height:0px"></div>
                                                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                                                </div>                                   

                    </div><!-- /.container -->
                </div>
```

Comment: Não rolou... Veja na imagem [link](https://webpaes.com.br/box-jquery.jpg)

Comment: @Jardel Qual é a div que tem a sombra?

Comment: @Jardel Tente mudando o seletor para `.wprt-image-box .item`.

Comment: não deu certo. Você utiliza boot 4 e eu 3.

`<script>
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
 $(".wprt-image-box .item").css("height","").each(function(){
  $(this).css("height",$(this).closest(".col-md-4").height()+"px");
 });
});
</script>
`
`.wprt-image-box.has-shadow { margin: 0 -15px; }
.wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item { padding: 0px 15px 30px; }
.wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item .inner { background-color: #fff; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 300px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); }`

Comment: eu fiz o que o Guilherme Nascimento indicou e deu certo:
`.wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item .inner { min-height: 400px;}`

Agora descobri o seletor. Como adaptar no seu script para dar certo também, pois no seu script é automático e não preciso fixar o tamanho.

Comment: @Jardel Atualizei o código. Faz um teste aí.

Comment: caiu como uma luva. Perfeito. Resolvido o problema. Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Eu diria que o caminho mais simples e que para o seu caso aonde o conteúdo **não é** dinâmico seria fixar uma altura minima com `min-height`, assim:

```css
.precos .col-md-4 {
    padding: 15px;
}
.item {
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="precos row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Usando Flex

Conforme este link você pode usar o http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/ que é um experimento, não foi implementado (http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css), deve ficar assim:

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.row-eq-height [class*="col-xs-"] {
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    height: 100%; /*acompanha a altura do pai*/
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="precos row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item">
       foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
       foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
       foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
       foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
       foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
       foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="item">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Relacionados

Postagens relacionadas:

- [Várias Divs com mesma Altura responsiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37750/3635)
- [Como fazer divs com mesma altura e 100% de altura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16630/3635)
- [Div height 100% em div height auto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180674/3635)

Comment: Isso não é uma boa. Por ser um layout responsivo, vai dar problema de exibição.

Comment: @Dvdsamm como não é? **é claro que é**, o conteudo é fixo, mesmo que o layout seja responsivo o conteudo conforme a ilustração do AP é um conteudo estático, ou seja o que muda na responsividade é somente as colunas e não o conteudo delas. De qualquer forma para casos de conteudos dinamicos existe o `row-eq-height`, conforme edição da resposta.

Comment: Usando `min-height` vc está se baseando na div que terá maior altura, ok! As outras, de menor altura, vão ficar com um espaço vazio na parte de baixo. Isso é Ok se as divs estiverem lado-a-lado como na imagem da pergunta, mas, e seu abrir num smartphone, as divs devem ficar uma embaixo da outra, e fica muito ruim uma div com um espaço em branco na parte de baixo. Não sei se deu pra entender.

Comment: @Dvdsamm isso não tem nada haver com responsividade, de qualquer forma mesmo que abra numa tela pequena se o AP assim desejar que as alturas "variem" novamente ele resolver com o um media-query (`@media`) a aplicar `min-height: 1px;`, mas de qualquer forma no smartphone o efeito dessas colunas irá lembrar "sections", sendo assim as sections podem sim ter algura minima. Eu usei um valor grande, mas o AP pode ajustar o min-height como quiser.

Comment: Melhor usar flex mesmo.

Comment: @Dvdsamm usar flex pra algo que seja dinamico é otimo, para algo que é estático e que se você olhar bem pra imagem vai notar que é pouca coisa de diferença (deve ter entre 10 e 12 pixels de diferença), mesmo no mobile não sentiria diferença. Outra coisa o uso do flex foi dica apenas, se aplicar flex ele perde todas as funcionalidades do responsivo "que quebra na tela conforme a necessidade", ou seja, além do flex ele vai precisa do media-query, penso usar tudo isso pra 10 pixels é o mesmo que usar um canhão pra matar formigas. Se for conteudo dinamico vale a pena, se for estático não.

Comment: Blz. Se usar min-height e @media juntos pode ficar até bom.

Comment: O conteúdo das divs são dinâmicos. Então não seria interessantes definir um height Quanto ao flex, como é um template bootstrap, creio que vai dar problema na responsividade...

Comment: Não me parecem dinamicos, você sabe o que significa dinamico né? De qualquer forma veja a solução com flex que esta na resposta. PS: use o campo de comentários para falar, o botão adicionar resposta é para resolução do problema.

Comment: Me corrija se estiver errado, mas entendo que dinâmico é quando busca resultado direto do banco, e não trazendo conteúdo estáticos por exemplo no próprio html.
Ah, me confundo muito na dinâmica de comentários e resposta aqui no stackoverflow... Desculpe.
Vou tentar o flex

Comment: sim esta correto, mas é principalmente aquele conteudo o qual você não tem controle, o qual pode variar muito. Como os seus divs todos tem o conheça mais, penso eu que o texto é sempre limitado e o resto é visto no após clicar no botão, logo você não precisa apelar pro Flex pra algo simples, se é simples use o simples. Não tem porque *usar um canhão pra matar formigas*.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento 
Tentei o flex conforme instruiu mas desconfigurou tudo... Talvez eu não soube adequar o exemplo no código.
[link](https://webpaes.com.br/box.JPG)

Comment: @Jardel vou revisar isso, de qualquer forma me parece muita pouca diferença de pixels pra você querer optar pelo flex ao invés de um simples `height`. Assim que terminar lhe aviso.

Comment: @Jardel exemplo editado, creio que de qualquer forma pra funcionar com a responsividade nativa do Bootstrap não será uma boa. Eu realmente acho que seus DIVs tem muito pouco texto pra vc se preocupar com Flex, use quando necessário e no caso que vocÊ esta usando claramente não vão ser divs gigantes contrastando com divs minusculas, não tem porque usar algo complexo pra resolver algo simples.

Comment: @Dvdsamm eu fiz como o @Guilherme Nascimento sugeriu e deu certo:
`.wprt-image-box.has-shadow .item .inner { min-height: 400px;`

Será que tem como adaptar seu script agora que sabemos qual o seletor que aplica a altura???

Comment: @Jardel Vou dar uma olhada aqui.