# Altura da row no bootstrap utilizando porcentagem (%)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, front-end

Como alterar a altura da *row* no *Bootstrap* usando porcentagem? Tentei a propriedade *height* tanto no *CSS*, quanto no *HTML* puro, e não deu certo.

Em poucas palavras, eu quero ter controle sobre a altura da *row*.

Na propriedade *Height*, percebi que se eu informar valor em pixel ( *px* ) ele funciona, porem gostaria de utilizar porcentagem ( *%* ), mas utilizando uma porcentagem, a propriedade não é reconhecida

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Bill Turner</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
    </head>   
    <style>
        .c{
            height: 50%;
            background-color:aquamarine;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row" height="50%">
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia colocar o código que está tendo dificuldade?

Comment: Geralmente o bootstrap é quem manda! Para que você volte ao domínio de seus estilos sempre coloque o `!important` na sua estilização. Isso quando se trata de boostrap.

Comment: Não é o caso. Tentei usar a estilização em linha, dessa forma deveria sobrepor a qualquer estilo externo

Comment: Em vez do `height`, tente aumentar o padding da `.table th, td {}`

Comment: !important depois do formato resolve o seu problema!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Alinhar altura 3 divs em uma linha - bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243010/alinhar-altura-3-divs-em-uma-linha-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos entender o porque `!important` não funciona nesse caso.

O tamanho padrão do documento *HTML* e do seu corpo ( *Body* ) é `auto`, esse tamanho muda conforme os elementos são inseridos neles, mais ainda continua tendo seu tamanho automático.

```js
console.log('Tamanho inicial: ' + $("body").height() + 'px');
console.log("Após 3 segundos ira criar um elemento.");

setTimeout(function() {
  var novoElemento = $("<div></div>").text("O tamanho do corpo mudou, confira o Log");
  $("body").append(novoElemento);
  console.log('Tamanho alterado para: ' + $("body").height() + 'px');
  console.log("Após 6 segundos ira criar outro elemento.");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    var novoElemento = $("<div></div>").text("O tamanho do corpo mudou novamente, confira o Log");
    $("body").append(novoElemento);
    console.log('Tamanho alterado para: ' + $("body").height() + 'px');
  }, 6000);
  
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Para que funcione com porcentagem você deve fazer o seguinte.

1. Definir o tamanho do documento *HTML*

   ```
   html {
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Definir o tamanho do *Body* e do seletor `.container`

   ```
   body, .container {
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```
3. Definir o tamanho do seletor `.row`

   ```
   .row {
       height: 50%;
   }
   ```

#### Veja funcionando

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 48%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
    <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">esp</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve alterar o valor do `line-height:` eu coloquei `2.0` mas você precisa ajustar isto no css custom (custom.css eu me refiro ao seu arquivo css) e inserir o atributo `!important` para que subscreva o do bootstrap.

```css
.c{
                        background-color:aquamarine;
                        line-height:2.0 !important;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">

            <div class="row" height="50%">
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row" height="50%">
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>
                <div class="c col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                    esp
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```